# Open source library like dotJ for rendering HTML tables with a Java object?

Tags: java, jsp

I'm rebuilding a legacy Servlet application to be JSP based and overall modernizing it.  Years ago I was at a company that used the dotJ library to take a Java object and do all the rendering of HTML table rows, with styles, bells, whistles and pagination if the results ran too long.   Since this was a while ago I am wondering if there is a BETTER library and an open source librarr.

The site will not be that complex, so I also have the question with how much hassle is the library.

Comment: Can you possibly use JSF?  It offers all sorts of table layout components and is one of the modern ways to program user interfaces in Java.

Comment: I've also been modernizing my own java knowledge, so thanks for the heads up about JSF.  Is it a set of libraries?  How big is the learning curve?

Comment: It's apart of Java Platform, Enterprise Edition (Java EE).  There are several libraries involved.  It will take a little bit (a week or two) to get going with it but there's a plethora of examples online that you can consult as you implement it.

Comment: Thanks much Zack, if you post that as an answer I will give you the points.  Your answer mentioned a critical point for me, it is part of Java, which sold me as I find that preferable to futzing with some other library.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[JavaServer Faces](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/jsf/info) offers all sorts of table layout components and is one of the modern ways to program user interfaces in Java.

It will take a little bit to get going with it but there's a plethora of examples online that you can consult as you implement it.

SOF in particular has some of the best JSF programmers in the world that offer excellent answers so be sure to check here and post questions if you run into hurdles using JSF.

Answer (score 0):

Four words: JSF, 2, dataTable, Primefaces ;)